# need help on select clause

Tags: sql, select

i have a table named record which contains four column branch,account,name,month.
now i want to find those data of this table which are present in current month, say month=3 but not present in previous month, say month=2. how to do???

say i have these values:
4 214 jones 3
4 213 jim   3
4 123 nitu  2
4 213 jim   2

now i want to find the record row
4 214 jones 3
since it is the new record and it was not present in previous month's record.
how to do?

Comment: An tell us what kind of Database you use....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the SQL Server:

```
SELECT  branch,account,name,month FROM record WHERE Month = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

`GETDATE()` gets the current date and `MONTH()` gets the month out of a date...

You can use `YEAR(), DAY()` etc functions for such things.

On MySQL just replace `MONTH(GETDATE())` with

```
MONTH(CURDATE())
```

To select a record that was not present in previous months just add this...

```
SELECT branch,account,name,month FROM record 
WHERE Month = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT NULL FROM record rec1 WHERE rec1.account = record.account and Month < MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: may be i can't explain what i want. i edited the question. please check